# finding repeat characters in a list for Hangman-python3

Tags: python, list

For my hangman application the code is as followed;

```
text=list(input("Enter the word to be guessed:"))
guess=[]
tries=5
clue=input("Enter a clue: ")
print('RULES:\n 1) type exit to exit applcation \n 2) type ? for the clue')

for i in range(len(text)):
    t='_ '
    guess.append(t)
print(guess)

while True:
    g=input("Guess a letter: ")
    if g in text:
        print("you guessed correct")
        y=text.index(g)
        guess[y]=g
        print(guess)
    continue
elif g=='exit':
    exit()
elif g=='?':
    print(clue)
elif tries==0:
    print ("you have run out of tries, bye bye")
    exit()
else:
    print(g,' is not in the word')
    tries -=1
    print("you have",tries,'tries left')
    continue
```

for the code for instance if the text to be guessed was 'avatar', when 'a' is guessed, it would return only the first instance of the letter and not for positions; text[2][4]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue comes from using `y = text.index(g)`. This will only return the index of the first match it finds. You need to do something more akin to the following:

```
if g in text:
    print("you guessed correct")
    for y in range(len(text)):
        if text[y] == g:
            guess[y] = g
    print(guess)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions to find the indices of a pattern.

```
>>import re
>> [i.start() for i in re.finditer('a', 'avatar')]
[0, 2, 4]
```

Comment: for some reason that is'nt working for me, will the code run for Python3.x?

Comment: y=[i.start() for i in re.finditer(g,text)]
  File "/Users/----/anaconda/lib/python3.5/re.py", line 220, in finditer
    return _compile(pattern, flags).finditer(string)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: This won't help while `text` is still a `list`. You ideally need to change to `text=input("Enter the word to be guessed:"))` and then should be able to use `[i.start() for i in re.finditer(g, text)]`

Comment: It's because you're taking input as a list and passing it into re.finditer, which expects a string. You can convert your list to a string with `''.join(text)`.